# The ranking of the Romanian Journal of Ophthalmology

Tags: publications

I searched the rank of the Romanian Journal of Ophthalmology but I did not find it on Scimago list of ophthalmology journals. The list ends with the 110-th journal: "Revue Francophone d'Orthoptie", having SJR 0.1 and H-index 2. 
However, I found something on Scopus, after clicking on letters "Ro": The Romanian Journal of Ophthalmology is the last Romanian Journal in that list, with an index of 0.05, and H index of 9. It is situated immediately under "Romani studies". 
In order to understand what is the effectiveness of printing there, I would like to ask you to approximate the ranking of the Romanian Journal of Ophthalmology in the continuation of Scimago list containing ophthalmology journals, extending it to 1000 journals.
The second purpose of my email is to ask why a journal with h-index 2 appears in Scimago List, and a journal with h-index 9 does not appear? 
Dr CDB

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what exactly you are asking. From all of the information you give, it's pretty clear that the journal is ranked pretty low -- how low exactly is probably not terribly important: nobody cares whether the journal is at rank 120 or 150 or 250 among ophthalmology journals.

Comment: If you publish to fulfill PhD requirement, discuss the matter with your advisor. If the journal is not on the "list" of valid journals, your work doesn't count towards your study. Once you publish in one journal you cannot submit the work to a "better journal" and by yourself an upgrade (this is considered self-plagiarism). Generally, journals with low ranking have low impact, so it may be that very few people will cite or even read your work.